# Realm java search Sub model?

Tags: java, android, realm

Really hard to **Google** this one as I am not entirely sure what it's called.

In my **android application** I have some **Models** to return some data from **`Realm`**.

Example structure:

**Shipment.java :**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class Shipment extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;

    public Technician technician;
```

**Technician.java :**

```
import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class Technician extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
```

So I am trying to return the shipments that correspond to a technician id.

In my **ShipmentsService.java** I have this:

```
public RealmResults<Shipment> forTechnician()
{
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    return realm.where(Shipment.class).contains("technician", "11");
}
```

Now I know that won't work but I am not sure how I can query based on this **relationship**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link queries. Also, `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` increments a ref count, so you probably shouldn't let it dangle there like that.

```
public RealmResults<Shipment> forTechnician(Realm realm) {
    return realm.where(Shipment.class).equalTo("technician.id", 11);
}
```

Comment: Getting an error saying that id needs to be an int but when I do that I get an error saying that it's expecting a string

Comment: equalTo seems to be the solution, not getting the right results back but thats a data issue I suspect

Comment: Whoops I copied the "11" from the code above but it should be an int

Answer (score 0):

You can do query like this :

```
public RealmResults<Shipment> forTechnician()
{
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    return realm.where(Shipment.class).equalTo("technician.id", 11).findAll();
}
```

Comment: Getting an error saying that id needs to be an int but when I do that I get an error saying that it's expecting a string

Comment: equalTo seems to be the solution, not getting the right results back but thats a data issue I suspect

Comment: yeah, you need to use equalTo instead of contains